# How to wait for data to be loaded from Firestore before running functions Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

## Current situation:

I have a service that reads the data from Cloud Firestore
from `employee.service.ts`:

```ts
getEmployeeList(orgID: string) {
    return this.firestore.collection('orgData').doc(orgID).collection('employeeList').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

I use this service to read the data in my component from `component.ts`:

```ts
export class ManageEmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
    newEmployee: FormGroup;
    Employees: Employee[];

    selectedOrganization: string;
  
    @Input() set selectOrg(org: string) {
      this.selectedOrganization = org;
      this.getEmployees();
      this.formsInit();
    }

    getEmployees() {
      this.employeeService.getEmployeeList(this.selectedOrganization).subscribe(data => {
        this.Employees = data.map(e => {
          return {
            id: e.payload.doc.id,
            ...e.payload.doc.data() as Employee
          };
        })
      });
    }

    formsInit() {
        //some reactive form stuff
    }
}
```

### The problem:

Every time the `selectOrg` input gets set, it runs `getEmployees` and `formsInit` synchronously. The problem is that I need some of the data from `getEmployees()` to be completely loaded before I run `formsInit()`.

## Question

How do I rewrite this code so that `formsInit` waits for `getEmployees` to complete its async operations?

**Edit 1:**
The best I can think right now is to modify `getEmployees()` to accept an optional argument that is a function for it to run once the data is retrieved. Not sure how practical or clean that would be, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just call `formsInit()` from your `getEmployees` function like so:

```
export class ManageEmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
    newEmployee: FormGroup;
    Employees: Employee[];

    selectedOrganization: string;
  
    @Input() set selectOrg(org: string) {
      this.selectedOrganization = org;
      this.getEmployees();
    }

    getEmployees() {
      this.employeeService.getEmployeeList(this.selectedOrganization).subscribe(data => {
        this.Employees = data.map(e => {
          return {
            id: e.payload.doc.id,
            ...e.payload.doc.data() as Employee
          };
        });
        this.formsInit();
      });
    }

    formsInit() {
        //some reactive form stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Is there any way I can pass a function to run and have it maintain scope? Issue I run into was if I passed formsInit as an argument to run, this.formsInit() would not run in the same scope as if I hard coded it, so it didn't have access to the data it needed